# Let $|X| \leqslant \omega$ then $X$ is finite or $|X| = |\mathbb{N}|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> a) Let $f: \mathbb{N} \to X$ be onto. Show there is a $g:X\to \mathbb{N}$ one-to-one such that $f(g(x)) = x, \forall x \in X$.
>
> b) Then use this to show if $X$ is countable, then $X$ is either finite or $|X|=|\mathbb{N}|$

It was easy to show that
$$g: x\mapsto \min\{n\in \mathbb{N}: f(n) = x\}$$

satifies a).

For b) I was thinking that it would be enough to write:

If $X$ is countable then $\exists f:\mathbb{N} \to X$ onto. The using a) a $g$ is found such that $|X| \leqslant |\mathbb{N}| = \omega.$

Since $|X| \leqslant \omega$ then $|X|=\omega$ or $|X| < \omega$. But I guess this is a bit to short sighted ($|X| < \omega$, isn't properly defined I guess).

I was given the alternative:

I) Let $g(X) \subseteq \{0, \ldots, N\}$ for a certain $N\in \mathbb{N}$, then $g:X\mapsto g(X)$ is bijective and thus $|X| = |g(X)|$ which is finite.

II) If not then, $(\forall N \in \mathbb{N})(\exists x \in X)(g(x) > N)$

Now I'm looking for a $h:\mathbb{N} \to X$ one-to-one. (which would imply $\omega \leqslant |X|$).

I was given $h:N\mapsto x_N$ where
$$x_N = f(\min \{n\in \mathbb{N}: g(f(n)) > N\})$$

But I don't see why each $x_N$ would be different... (or why this $h$ would be one-to-one)

Could someone clarify?

Comment: I would say: $g(X)$ is well-ordered, so it is order-isomorphic to an initial segment of $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{N}$ is order-isomorphic to an initial segment of $g(X)$. Show that $\mathbb{N}$ cannot be order-isomorphic to a proper initial segment of one of its subsets.

Comment: Note that $g$ is a bijection between $X$ and some set of natural numbers. All you need now is to show that every set of natural numbers is either finite or bijective with $\Bbb N$, And for that, consider the function that carries $n$ to the $n$-th least element of the set.